# determine file path for pandas.read_csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use the following code to read a csv file and save it as pandas data frame, but the method always return the iris dataset not my data. What is the problem?

```
    import pandas as pd
    a = pd.read_csv(r"D:\data.csv")
    print(a)
```

Comment: Are you sure your data is contained in that file?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I really can not understand the reason

Comment: I think the way i address the path is not correct